# Print a given string backwards with a recursive function, without using <string.h>

Tags: c

I'll summarize the problem that goes in my homework:

"Write a recursive function that receives a char array given by the user, prints it backwards and doesn't return anything. The function must end the process and return when \0 is found". Don't use the string.h library, and don't use pointers."

I kind of managed to get the recursive way of doing it, but I'm failing at the function definition.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help. What is your question? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you aren't sure how to ask a good question.

Comment: The "don't use pointers" command is going to make it tricky.  You're passed a string, which is basically a pointer, but you can't use pointers — a peculiar requirement.

Comment: Your summary of the problem is a patent contradiction. Any function in C that receives a `char[]` is, in fact, receiving a pointer. Perhaps you should widen the summary a bit.

Comment: "I kind of managed to get the recursive way of doing it," --> post that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing more than a revamp of Gardener's answer, without *technically* using pointers (because there are no little `*` thingies).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void recursive_print(char array[]) {
  if (array[0] != '\0') {
    recursive_print(array + 1); //pointer arithmetic, but no '*', so not a pointer supposedly
    printf("%c", array[0]);
  }
  else {
    printf("\n");  // send a new line at the end to make it look better.
  }
}

int main() {
  char string[] = "Hello";
  recursive_print(string);
  return 0;
}
```

Although, I would add that if your instructor is making this (counter-productive) distinction about the use of pointers, you might want to remember that just as all books about C are not equally good, the same thing can be said of instructors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.  With recursive functions, the biggest problem is making sure you have the right exit condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void recursive_print(char* array) {
  if(*array != '\0') {
    recursive_print(&array[1]);
    printf("%c", *array);
  } else {
    printf("\n");  // send a new line at the end to make it look better.
  }
}

int main()
{
  char string[] = "Hello";
  recursive_print(string);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello! I tried something similar, but the problem is that I can't use pointers (which gives this code the real problem, to be honest).